# Pipeline object to function to create xml

Tags: xml, powershell

**Update: See the bottom for a working example.**

I'm trying to create XML files with a object as input tough a pipeline:

```
Get-ActiveDirectoryForest -Domain $Domain | GenerateXml
```

How can I pass a object to a other function and use this object to create a XML file? The object that get's passed throug always has the same first Property (TableName), the rest is different.

My Object looks like:

```
TableName                   Domain      User        Status      UNC
Network-Domain-Locked users test.local  John Doe    Locked      John.Doe@test.local
Network-Domain-Locked users test.local  Jane Doe    Locked      Jane.Doe@test.local
```

And the function that I've created:

```
Function GenerateXml {
[CmdLetBinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [Object]$Object,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [String]$TableName
    )
    Begin {

        $XmlExportPath = $Script:Settings.XmlFolder
        If ((Test-Path -Path $XmlExportPath\export.xml)) {
            Remove-Item -Path $XmlExportPath\export.xml -Force
        }

Add-Content -Path $XmlExportPath\export.xml -Value @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportFile>
    <Module Name="Network-Collection">
        <Task>Test export object</Task>
    </Module>
    <Input TableName="$TableName">
'@
    }
    Process {
        Try {
            $TableName = $Object.TableName  #Can't find the property on the object..
            Write-Host "Database tabel: $TableName"

            $(foreach ($Item in $Object) {
                Add-Content -Path $XmlExportPath\export.xml -Value '@`t`t<$($Item.Key)>$($Item.Value)</$($Item.Key)>@'
            })
        }
        Catch { Write-Error $_ }
    } 
    End {
Add-Content -Path $XmlExportPath\export.xml -Value @'
    </Input>
</BitImportFile>
'@
    } # End Region
}
```

**@Update:**
- I've removed the Mandatory=$True and found out that the Object is accesable trough `$_.
- The question about the xml remains

**@Update 2: Working example**

```
Function GenerateXml {

[CmdLetBinding()]

    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [Object]$Object,

        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [String]$TableName
    )

    Begin {
        $XmlExportFile = "C:\Temp\Export.xml"

        [xml]$Xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportFile>
    <Module Name="" Date="" />
    <Input TableName="">
    </Input>
</ImportFile>
'@
    }

    Process {
        Try {
            $XmlNode = $Xml.ImportFile
            $XmlNode.Module.Name = $_.TaskName
            $XmlNode.Input.TableName = $_.TableName
            $XmlProperties = $_.PSObject.Properties

            Foreach ($XmlProp in ($XmlProperties | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "TaskName" -and $_.Name -ne "TableName"})) {
                $Name = $XmlProp.Name
                $Value = $XmlProp.Value

                $newRole = $xml.CreateElement($Name)
                $Xml.ImportFile.Input.AppendChild($newRole) | Out-Null
                $newRole.SetAttribute("Value",$Value);
            }
        }
        Catch { Write-Error $_ }
    } 

    End {
        $Xml.Save("$XmlExportFile")
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried just piping your output to CovertTo-XML ?

Comment: Yes I've tried, but then I'll get the wrong output in the XML file. This way it's fully customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the CovertTo-XML output is not to your liking and you want to build out your XML file manually you would do this.

Make the basis for your XML document and store it in a variable:

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportFile>
    <Module Name="Network-Collection">
        <Task>Test export object</Task>
    </Module>
    <Input TableName="$TableName">
    </Input>
</ImportFile>
'@
```

now that you have the shell of your file you can append new nodes where ever you want. You would likely do a foreach object and create XML elements and attributes as needed for that record. Then you attach it back to the parent node that already exists.

```
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement('Test') # Here we make a XML element that is compatible with with $xml document as a whole.

$xml.ImportFile.Input.appendNode($newNode) # and here we attach that Test node to the existing Input node.
```

If you wanted to add an attribute you would add it to $newNode before you appended it, like this:

```
$newNode.SetAttribute('name','myDomain')
```

Comment: Cool, I'll definently change my code with this. It looks much cleaner. But how do I implement this with the Begin, Process, End parts. In my understanding Begin / End gets proccesed once and Process is started for each member in a pipline object like: (Get-Process | GenerateXml)

Comment: Hmm, just a thought: Should I create the XML variable in Begin, append to it in Process and write the variable with $XML.Save in End?...

Comment: Yup, you have got it.

Comment: Nice, I've updated the question with my final script. So others can see and learn how this works. If you see any errors, please let me know :)